# Xcode 5 won't open .xib

Tags: ios, xcode

I just updated xcode 5 with iOS 7 and now I get the following error with most of my .xib files:

`The document "EpisodesVC.xib" could not be opened. The operation couldn’t be completed. -[NSConcreteValue ibInsetValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f998b3a2dd0.`

The console doesn't offer any more information than the previous message. Some of my more simple XIB files will still open.

I can post contents of the XIB file if that's helpful.

**UPDATE:**

link to xml contents

http://pastebin.com/fa7TiHZp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the following section from the source fixed it (see source link in question):

```
<object class="NSValue" key="IBUISeparatorInset">
    <bytes key="$0">ez89ZGRkZH0AA</bytes>
    <double key="$1">0.0</double>
    <double key="$2">0.0</double>
    <double key="$3">0.0</double>
    <double key="$4">0.0</double>
</object>
```

I should have known to look for that from the `ibInsetValue` error...

Answer (score 2):

I found this on Stack. Someone had the same problem going from 3.1 to 4.0.

Try this: goto XCode Menu => File => Add Files to your-project, a finder-like browser will pop up. Navigate to your Classes directory. Do you see the EpisodesVC.xib and can you click on it? Then add it to your project.

Comment: It was greyed out in that dialog. I tried deleting it from the project and then adding it this way, and it still produces the same error.

Comment: Maybe the file is corrupt. xib is just a xml textfile, can you look into it with textedit or such (don't edit it), if you see something strange? Normally it is neatly formatted.
Can you go back a version ? Maybe on a friends Mac ?

Comment: It's fine in textedit. A few other files have the same issue, but not all of them. I think it's a specific layout item or property that is causing the issue. I'll update with the source tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Storyboard file on Xcode 5, And then: 1. Open file inspector 2. On "Interface Builder Documents" section change "Open with" to Xcode 4.6 (if it's 5.x). 3. Save, Close the project and open that with old Xcode.It should work then.

If that doesn't, you could try the following.

Open the storyboard file with TextEdit or any text editor of your choice. 
Look for this line :

```
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.xib" version ="3.0">
```

and changing the version value from "3.0" to "2.0"

Let me know if it works for you. Good luck !

Comment: Unfortunately, "Opens in" is disabled.